# Assigning a value to numpy array with a boolean mask: how to?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, boolean

I am trying to assign a value, at a specific index, to a numpy vector on which I first want to apply a boolean mask (critically, I want my indexing to refer the "masked" array). However, surprisingly, the following doesn't seem to work:

Let's say I want to change the first value of the "valid" vector (the one where the mask is True), i.e., the second "absolute" value of the vector.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.full(4, np.nan)
mask = np.array([False, True, True, True])
index = 0

x[mask][index] = 3
x 
>>> array([nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `x[np.where(mask)[0][index]] = 3` ??? I.e use 'where' to get the index corresponding to main array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` at the end will be treated as you're indexing the finished mask, here is the proof:

```
>>> x[mask]
array([ nan,  nan,  nan])
>>> x[mask][index]
nan
>>>
```

So it is virtually changing the `nan` to `3`, but that `nan` is not stored anywhere, so nothing will change, use:

```
x[np.where(mask)[0][index]] = 3
print(x)
```